Stepper Motor Direction Not Changing with Toggle Switch - Need Help
I’m trying to control the direction of a stepper motor using a toggle switch with my Arduino. While the LED indicates that the switch is working correctly (i.e., it changes state as expected), the stepper motor's direction does not change as anticipated. Here’s the code I’m using:
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 2048; // Number of steps per revolution
const int motSpeed = 10;             // Motor speed (RPM)

// Pin configuration
const int buttonPin = 2;             // Button pin number
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;      // Built-in LED pin number

// State variables
int motDir = 1;                      // Motor direction (1 = forward, -1 = backward)
int newVal;                          // Current button state
int oldVal = HIGH;                   // Previous button state
unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // Last debounce time
unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;    // Debounce delay (ms)
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                  // Initialize serial communication
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);    // Set button pin with pull-up resistor
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);             // Set LED pin as output
  myStepper.setSpeed(motSpeed);        // Set motor speed
}

void loop() {
  // Read button state
  int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // Debounce handling
  if (reading != oldVal) {
    lastDebounceTime = millis(); // Record the time of last state change
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
    // Check if button state has changed
    if (reading != newVal) {
      newVal = reading;

      // Toggle direction on button press
      if (newVal == LOW) {
        motDir = -motDir; // Reverse motor direction

        // Toggle LED state
        digitalWrite(ledPin, (motDir == 1) ? LOW : HIGH);

        Serial.print("Motor Direction: ");
        Serial.println((motDir == 1) ? "Clockwise" : "Counter-Clockwise");
      }
    }
  }

  // Rotate motor
  myStepper.step(motDir * 10); // Move motor by 10 steps

  // Update previous button state
  oldVal = reading;

  // Delay for smooth operation
  delay(20);
}

Problem:
The LED and serial monitor correctly show the change in state when the switch is pressed and released.
However, the stepper motor does not change its direction as expected. It seems to continue rotating in the same direction regardless of the switch state.
What I've Tried:

Checked Hardware Connections:

Verified that the stepper motor and driver connections are correct.

Checked power supply to the stepper motor.


Code Review:

Ensured debounce logic is correctly implemented.
Verified that the motDir variable is being updated correctly.

Request for Help:
Can someone help identify what might be causing the stepper motor direction not to change? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.


I know you said the button works. But the code uses a pull up but in the diagram the button is connected to the positive rail.  Probably want to connect the button tot he negative rail.

Are you really powering the stepper motor with a small rectangle 9 volt battery? This likely does not have enough current to work dependably.

I am unfamiliar with the way the stepper motor is wired. Can you include a part number or a detailed description of the stepper motor in your question (not here, but in your question).

Some prototyping board power connectors do not span the entire length of the board. Check your prototyping board and add jumpers if necessary.

Sometimes the coil wiring is different than expected.  Try swapping pairs of pins, like myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 10, 9, 11);

Sounds like you have tested everything. Try to test the motor separately. Only the motor and the Arduino. All other components should be removed. This will show if the motor itself is faulty. For future use, you can design a motor stepper motor control board like this: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Stepper_motor_developing_platform_d2e5fcf7.html
